# Nhibernate mapping one to zero or one - with left join

Tags: nhibernate, one-to-one

I have class `Place` which may or may not have one `User`.

```
// I have nothing on User related to Place
public PlaceMap()
{
    Id( x=> x.Id, "id").GeneratedBy.Identity();
    References(x => x.UserManager, "user_manager_id").Nullable().Cascade.All();
}
```

When querying over `Place`, I want always to left join since it is `Nullable`.
The problem is that the generated sql has `inner join`.

The query:

```
var queryList = _dalSession.CreateCriteria<T>();
queryList.CreateAlias("UserManager", "UserManager");
```

Comment: quick heads up: I've updated the answer thanks to a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly set the join type when calling `CreateAlias`:

```
using NHibernate.SqlCommand;

// ...

var queryList = _dalSession.CreateCriteria<T>();
queryList.CreateAlias("UserManager", "UserManager", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
```

If you want to make this behavior the default, you can do so via the mapping.

- In mapping by configuration file, specify `fetch="join"
- With FluentNH, specify `.Fetch.Join()`

Using NHibernate mapping-by-code:

```
classMapper.ManyToOne(
      x => x.UserManager,
      manyToOneMapper =>
      {
          manyToOneMapper.Column("user_manager_id");
          manyToOneMapper.NotNullable(false);
          manyToOneMapper.Lazy(LazyRelation.NoLazy);
          manyToOneMapper.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
      }
 )
```

Comment: Thanks, Can I do it via mapping and not query?

Comment: @Shazam - I cannot see a way to make this the default behavior via mapping. It would probably be argued that it's best to specify this on a query level anyway.

Comment: I do believe it is best to do this at query level, but if you need to do it in mapping, see the [NHibernate docs](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone): `fetch="join"`.  With FluentNH, that's `.Fetch.Join()`

Comment: @DanielSchilling - Thanks for that. I've incorporated your information into the answer.